# outlook restapi does not load calendars events for outllok personal account

Tags: calendar, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I have been using outlook rest api's to read/create/update calendar events of outlook account.

Followed all the steps https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/

It works very well for the subscription account's.

But the api does not work to load the calendar events of my personal outlook account ex: phani.xxx@outlook.com.

API responds with below error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorMissingEmailAddress",
    "message": "When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids."
}
```

I have tried the same with outlook sandbox got the same response.

Any help on this to get this api working for any outlook account. Will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to your account not yet being enabled for the REST API. There's an issue with the v2 endpoint not returning the proper error message in this case.

Comment: how to enable my account for REST API ?. does that mean that all the acconts which my code want to read data should be REST API enabled. And this is not required for subscription account ?

Comment: All Office 365 accounts are REST-enabled. Outlook.com accounts will all be enabled, but are being enabled in batches, so it's a matter of waiting until your account gets enabled as part of our process.